# Need to print Five sequence number for one sale.order other than ir.sequence

Tags: odoo, any

I have writen code to print five sequence number for 1 sale order
but it affect last sale order number , it was jumping 5 order numbers

I have to print 5 sequence number for 1 sale order without ir sequence

```
 ticket = fields.Char(string="Ticket", readonly=True, required=True, copy=False, default='New')

 @api.multi
  def action_confirm(self): 
    result = super(SaleOrder, self).action_confirm()

    len_count = []
    ticket_list = []
    tickets = ""
    count = 5
    for i in range(count):
        x = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('sale.order')
        if not len(len_count) == 5:
            if not tickets:
                tickets = x 
            else:
                tickets = tickets + ',' + x
    print tickets
    print 'abc'


    ticket_list.append(str(tickets))
    self.ticket = ticket_list
    print ticket_list
    ctx = dict(self.env.context or {})
    ctx.update({
        'sale_action_new': ticket_list,
        })    
    print ctx

    template = self.env.ref('sale_order.email_template_ticket')
    template.with_context(ctx).send_mail(self.id)
```

Comment: give some code example

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: actually i need to generate 5 lottory number for one sale order if i confrom the sale order means need to generate 5 sequence number and update it in ticket field

Comment: For example saleorder number = 34 and you want to generate 34,35,36,37,38 for that saleorder?

Comment: Can you get into more detail? I don't understand why you're using the `sale.order` sequence instead of another one for tickets. The rest of the code is not the prettiest one, but should work as intended. If it's not working as intended, please add what actual and target value are for your requirement.

Comment: Yesh Adam, But if i create new sale.order it will jump to 39

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to help.

```
start = self.id               //sales-order id
limit = start + 5 
for x in range(start, limit):
   if not tickets:
      tickets = x 
   else:
       tickets = tickets + ',' + x
```